# Display Image of IFormFile saved as Byte in database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

This is my code in ASP.NET CORE 3.0, when I save the image using type as IFormFile in View Model and as Byte in model. Now I want to retrieve this image in Edit Method. I am Unable to display image. Here is my code

```
var formData = new Student()
                        {
                            AppUserID = userId,
                            FirstName = model.FirstName,
                            MatricMarks = model.MatricMarks,
                            CollegeName = model.CollegeName,
                            HSSCMarks = model.HSSCMarks,

                        };
                        if (model.Profile != null && model.Profile.FileName != "" && model.Profile.FileName != null)
                        {
                            IFormFile file = model.Profile;


                            if (file.Length > 0)

                            //Convert Image to byte and save to database

                            {
                                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(stream);
                                    formData.Profile = stream.ToArray();
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class StudentSignUpViewModel
    {


        public string Username { get; set; }

        public string CollegeName { get; set; }

        public string HSSCMarks { get; set; }

        public IFormFile Profile { get; set; }
}
```

**here is Model class**

```
    public string MatricMarks { get; set; }
    public string CollegeName { get; set; }
    public string   HSSCMarks { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte[] Profile { get; set; }
```

**And here is Edit[GET] Method where Im trying to display image, please guide what went wrong**

```
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            StudentSignUpViewModel model = new StudentSignUpViewModel();
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var student = _context.Students.Where(x => x.StudentId == id.Value).Include(x=>x.AppUser).FirstOrDefault();
            model.MatricMarks = student.MatricMarks;
                model.CollegeName = student.CollegeName;
                model.HSSCMarks = student.HSSCMarks;
                model.CoursesArray = student.Courses;

                var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(student.Profile);
                ViewBag.imgSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}",model.Profile, base64);
                }
```

**View Method where I'm Trying to display image**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <img src="@ViewBag.imgSrc" class="profile-user-img img-responsive img-circle" alt="User profile picture" />

                        <label asp-for="Username" class="control-label"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Username" class="form-control" />
```

**Note: Irrelevant Code is cut out**.

Comment: Actually it`s not a good idea to store images that way, is it necessary?  
You can just save them like files in your project's resources.
Read this [article](https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/)

Answer (score 0):

To display binary image using base64 string, please modify your code as below.

```
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(student.Profile);

ViewBag.imgSrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
```

Besides, you can also save these image file(s) on your web server rather than storing them in database, so that your app can serve these images directly to clients.

For more information about serving static files, please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1